# android.widget.ArrayAdapter<T> just accept row template

Tags: android

I am developing an android application which contains a ListAtivity class and get it is data as follow :

```
ArrayAdapter<Item> ara=new MyArrayAdapter(this,_items);

setListAdapter(ara);
```

And I defined MyArrayAdapter :

```
....
public MyArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<BirthdayContact> list) {
        super(context,R.layout.list_row,0,list);
        //super(context, R.layout.birthday_list, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;

    }
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.birthday_list_row, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder._cName= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
            viewHolder._cImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_image);
            viewHolder._cbirthDay=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contact_birthday_remained);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
              }
```

......

But the problem with this way is that you cant only assign each row`s template and you cant have other widget on list view which are not part of list of data. I mean I want to have a say a TextView which shows messages to user, and below that I show the list of rows.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a different layout than a simple `ListView` you have the option of setting the content view to a layout file like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout_with_diferrent_views); // call this on the onCreate() method
```

where `R.layout.layout_with_different_views` could be a xml layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Because you extends `ListActivity` you must have in the layout a `ListView` element with the id `@android:id/list`. Of course you can have a more complex layout than the one above as long as you have a `ListView` element with the id `@android:id/list`

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a listHeader : lv.addHeaderView(findViewById(R.id.header));
This has to be done in your onCreate method in your activity, and you must provide a widget with the id header.

Comment: What if I want to put buttons or some other textviews. And If I want to use addHeaderView(...), where exactly should I put the widget ? in the raw template ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want other components in activity.Then better consider Normal Activity instead ListActivity.

Comment: Is it possible to fill listview by using 'MyArrayAdapte' in a normal activity ?