# make ListView uniquely identifiable in android

Tags: android, android-listview

As I read from [android sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html), if I use SimpleCursorAdapter, it automatically set the id of list view to primary key of the table, so if I call the following event :

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
 ......
}
```

I can easily determine which item (row) of database has been selected, by reading the id parameter.

But I am populating my list view by implementing my own custom ArrayAdapter. As I explained in my former [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444101/android-widget-arrayadaptert-just-accept-row-template/). So I don't know how to get the selected ID of list view item.

My table just has two column, the _Id of long type and is primary key, and name of nvarchar type.

Thanks.

Comment: So... you want to find out which item was clicked when onListItemClick is called?

Comment: Yes, and so I could be able to deal with Database

Comment: The position of the clicked item within your Adapter is stored in the parameter position. Uhm... I guess that isn't what you meant?

Comment: No, cause position cant help me to know the primary key value of selected item.

Comment: Then why don't you simply use the SimpleCursorAdapter you are referring to in your question? Doesn't that example contain any valuable code?

Comment: Cause I gather my data not only from database table, also I get some data from Contact API, and put them all in a one class, then return this class as a List<T> to my custom adapter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8238/discussion-between-m1ntf4n-and-persian-dev)

Comment: ok lets continue this in chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `List<T>` consists of custom data container objects, you just have to add a method such as `getPrimaryKey()` to that data container class. Now, in the method `onListItemClicked`, you can easily read that key by doing

```
DataContainer dataContainer = myDataList.get(position);
int primaryKey = dataContainer.getPrimaryKey();
```

or simply

```
int primaryKey = myDataList.get(position).getPrimaryKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend CursorAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter.  Then override bindView and newView to implement custom logic and behaviour.

Comment: Is there a tutorial or sample? I am a newbie to android development.